# What does this question from SL Loney Coordinate Geometry mean?

Tags: complex-numbers, analytic-geometry

Given question :

> $x+iy = tan(u+iv)$ where $x, y, u, v$ are all real, prove that the curves u = constant give a family of coaxal circles passing through the point $(0, 1)$ and $(0, -1)$ and that the curves v = constant give a system of circles cutting the first given system orthogonally

I don't seem to understand what this question wants to ask. I am only a beginner in complex numbers and I know how to find the tan of a complex number. I thought I may need to equate the real and imaginary parts of both sides and then find a relation between x and y but how do I then deal with the sinh and cosh. It seems too complicated that way.

Comment: I don't understand the question either.  Are you sure you haven't left something out?

Comment: No it's the exact same text

Comment: I thought it might mean something like this: if we fix $u$ the right-hand side is a function of the parameter $v$ and so determines a curve in the complex plane.  Similarly if we fix $v$ instead.  Then it seems to say that these curves are circles with certain properties.  But this isn't true.  If $u=0$ then the right-hand side is pure imaginary, so the curve is the imaginary axis.

Comment: Where's the question from?

Comment: @rschwieb From S L Loney Coordinate Geometry, chapter on System of circles examples XXIV, no. 11

Comment: @ShubhraneelPal I think, perhaps, since this was first printed 122 years ago, you should provide an edition/year, too.

Comment: @rschwieb this is 2017 edition printed by Arihant publishers